# Ajax Control Toolkit Reorderlist javascript call

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a ReorderList from the Ajax Control Toolkit on an aspx page. What I want to do is to enable a button after the order of the items have been changed.

I already have the javascript function in my page in a script block, but how can I tell the ReorderList to call the javascript after order has been changed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who also has the same question, use jQuery to accomplish this...